# Как решать задачки на комбинаторику без itertools?

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Задачка вот эта:
https://py.checkio.org/ru/mission/place-queens/

На всякий копирую условие сюда:

> В этой задаче нам понадобятся только Ферзи. Ферзь ходит на любое количество клеток по вертикали, горизонтали и диагоналям.
>
> Вам нужно разместить 8 ферзей на шахматной доске 8 на 8, так чтобы ни
> один ферзь не мог атаковать никого другого. Мы уже разместили
> несколько ферзей, так что вам нужно только закончить расположение.
>
> Дан набор координат, где уже расположены ферзи. Закончите этот набор и
> верните все координаты для восьми ферзей. Если этого невозможно
> сделать - верните пустой набор. И возможна такая ситуация, что уже в
> начальном расположении один ферзь угрожает другому.

Я обычно решаю подобные задачки с помощью permutations из itertools, но в этой задаче вариантов так много, что все просто стопорится на переборе вариантов и не идет дальше. Поэтому такой вопрос: как кроме как с помощью itertools решать подобные задачки?
Только не надо кидать сюда решение полностью, просто обозначьте сам принцип, и какие инструменты для этого нужны. Спасибо заранее.

На всякий случай, мой индийский код:

```
def hits(x, y, chess, tp=False):
    if type(chess)==tuple:
        chess=list(chess)
    for n, a in enumerate(chess):
        if type(a)==tuple:
            chess[n]=list(a)

    x1, x2 = x + 1, x - 1
    y1, y2 = y + 1, y - 1
    # straight hits of queens
    while x1 < 8 or x2 >= 0 or y1 < 8 or y2 >= 0:
        if x1 < 8:
            if chess[x1][y]==3:
                if tp: return False
                x1 += 1
            else:
                chess[x1][y] = 1
                x1 += 1
        if x2 >= 0:
            if chess[x2][y]==3:
                if tp: return False
                x2 -= 1
            else:
                chess[x2][y] = 1
                x2 -= 1
        if y1 < 8:
            if chess[x][y1]==3:
                if tp: return False
                y1 += 1
            else:
                chess[x][y1] = 1
                y1 += 1
        if y2 >= 0:
            if chess[x][y2]==3:
                if tp: return False
                y2 -= 1
            else:
                chess[x][y2] = 1
                y2 -= 1

    x1, x2 = x + 1, x - 1
    y1, y2 = y + 1, y - 1
    x3, x4 = x + 1, x - 1
    y3, y4 = y - 1, y + 1
    # diagonal hits of queens
    while x1 < 8 and y1 < 8 or x2 >= 0 and y2 >= 0:
        if x1 < 8 and y1 < 8:
            if chess[x1][y1]==3:
                if tp: return False
                x1 += 1
                y1 += 1
            else:
                chess[x1][y1] = 1
                x1 += 1
                y1 += 1
        if x2 >= 0 and y2 >= 0:
            if chess[x2][y2]==3:
                if tp: return False
                x2 += 1
                y2 += 1
            else:
                chess[x2][y2] = 1
                x2 -= 1
                y2 -= 1

        if x3 < 8 and y3 >= 0:
            if chess[x3][y3]==3:
                if tp: return False
                x3 += 1
                y3 -= 1
            else:
                chess[x3][y3] = 1
                x3 += 1
                y3 -= 1
        if x4 >= 0 and y4 < 8:
            if chess[x4][y4]==3:
                if tp: return False
                x4 -= 1
                y4 += 1
            else:
                chess[x4][y4] = 1
                x4 -= 1
                y4 += 1

    if tp: return True
    return chess


def place_queens(placed):
    signs = 'abcdefgh'

    chess = []
    for x in range(8):
        chess.append([0] * 8)

    for x in placed:
        a = 8 - int(x[1])
        b = signs.index(x[0])
        chess[a][b] = 3
        chess = hits(a, b, chess)

    chess2 = chess.copy()
    for n, x in enumerate(chess2):
        chess2[n] = tuple(x)
    chess2 = tuple(chess2)

    zeros = []
    for a, x in enumerate(chess):
        for b, y in enumerate(x):
            if y == 0:
                zeros.append([a, b])

    import itertools as it
    variations = list(it.permutations(zeros, r=len(zeros)))

    res = []
    for x in variations:
        res.append([])
        for y in x:
            neo = hits(y[0], y[1], chess, True)
            if neo:
                chess[a][b] = 3
                new_queen = signs[b] + str(8 - a)
                res[-1].append(new_queen)
        for n, x in enumerate(chess2):
            chess[n] = list(x)

    res = sorted(res, key=len)

    print('CHESS2')
    for x in chess2:
        print(x)
    print()


    return res[-1]


print(place_queens({"b2", "c4", "d6", "e8"}))  # {"b2", "c4", "d6", "e8", "a5", "f3", "g1", "h7"},
print(place_queens({"b2", "c4", "d6", "e8", "a7", "g5"}))  # == set())
```

Comment: Рекурсия, которая идёт по рядам. На каждой итерации идёт по сторлбцам и ищет куда можно поставить ферзя чтобы выполнились условия. Если не получается, то возвращается на шаг назад и идёт в следующий столбец уже там. Если расставил всех, печатает позиции.

Comment: Так для этого нужна не рекурсия, а цикл for, там же так и сделано. Сначала я исключила все поля которые бьют уже расставленные ферзи, и дальше циклом расставляются новые ферзи, проблема в том, что когда ферзь ставится на одно место - он бьет остальные, тем самим исключая свободные места из выборки. Таким образом расставляется меньше ферзей чем возможно.

Comment: Так рекурсия как раз и позволяет при "заходе в тупик" немного откатиться и попробовать другой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации с использованием рекурсии:

```
# перевод координат из строки в пару (ряд, столбец): "b1" -> (0,1)
str2coord = lambda s: (int(s[1])-1, ord(s[0])-ord('a'))
# обратная функция
coord2str = lambda c: chr(c[1]+ord('a'))+str(c[0]+1)

# проверка что 2 ферзя не бьют труг друга
def can_be_placed(p1, p2):
    (r1,c1), (r2,c2) = p1, p2
    return r1 != r2 and c1 != c2 and abs(r2-r1) != abs(c2-c1)

# проверка что новый ферзь не бьёт ни один из уже установленных
can_be_placed_on_board = lambda queens, pos: all(can_be_placed(p, pos) for p in queens)
# проверка на занятость ряда
is_row_occupied = lambda queens, r: sum(1 for p in queens if p[0]==r)

def place_one_queen(queens, r):
    # в списке 8 ферзей - значит всех расставили
    if len(queens) == 8: return set(map(coord2str, queens))
    # вышли за границу доски - тут нам делать нечего
    if r == 8: return set()
    if is_row_occupied(queens, r):
        # в текущем ряду уже занято - попытаемся в следующем
        return place_one_queen(queens, r+1)
    for c in range(8):
        # идём по столбцам и пытаемся поставить ферзя
        if can_be_placed_on_board(queens, (r,c)):
            # можно поставить - ставим и переходим на следующий ряд
            result = place_one_queen(queens+[(r,c)], r+1)
            # вернулись с результатом - значит дальше можно не искать - возвращаемся и передаём результат выше 
            if result: return result
    return set()

def place_queens(positions):
    queens = []
    # размещаем исходных ферзей и проверяем, что они не бьют друг друга
    for pos in positions:
        coord = str2coord(pos)
        if not can_be_placed_on_board(queens, coord):
            return set()
        queens.append(coord)

    return place_one_queen(queens, 0)

# просто печатаем положение ферзей на доске (для наглядности)
def print_board(queens):
    coords = list(map(str2coord, queens))
    print(' ', *list(map(chr, range(65, 65+8))))
    for r in range(7,-1,-1):
        print(r+1, end=' ')
        for c in range(8):
            print('X' if (r,c) in coords else '*', end=' ')
        print(r+1)
    print(' ', *list(map(chr, range(65, 65+8))))

result = place_queens({"d4"})
print(result)
print_board(result)
print()
result = place_queens({"b2", "c4", "d6", "e8"})  # {"b2", "c4", "d6", "e8", "a5", "f3", "g1", "h7"},
print(result)
print_board(result)
print()
print(place_queens({"b2", "c4", "d6", "e8", "a7", "g5"}))  # == set())
```

```
['d4', 'b1', 'e2', 'g3', 'a5', 'h6', 'f7', 'c8']
  A B C D E F G H
8 * * X * * * * * 8
7 * * * * * X * * 7
6 * * * * * * * X 6
5 X * * * * * * * 5
4 * * * X * * * * 4
3 * * * * * * X * 3
2 * * * * X * * * 2
1 * X * * * * * * 1
  A B C D E F G H

['b2', 'e8', 'd6', 'c4', 'g1', 'f3', 'a5', 'h7']
  A B C D E F G H
8 * * * * X * * * 8
7 * * * * * * * X 7
6 * * * X * * * * 6
5 X * * * * * * * 5
4 * * X * * * * * 4
3 * * * * * X * * 3
2 * X * * * * * * 2
1 * * * * * * X * 1
  A B C D E F G H

None
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но оно порется на данном тесте: 
Fail: place_queens({"b1", "c4", "d6", "e8"}) С комментом: TypeError: Must be set., ?, ?

Comment: Ну, верните `set()` там где сейчас возвращает *None* / *False*. включая конец функции `place_one_queen`.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за решение, оно вроде как правильно работает, я потом еще гляну на других тестах и буду разбираться в Вашем коде.)

Answer (score 0):

Как один из лучших вариантов - рекурсия, как писали в комментариях и ответах выше. Но если вам не очень важно время выполнения программы, то можно написать генетический алгоритм для этого, однако для конкретно этой задачи *крайне не рекомендую* это делать. Пишу этот ответ для того, чтобы вы знали, что существует такой способ и могли его использовать там, где это действительно нужно.
Почитать побольше про генетический алгоритм можно [здесь](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wVQr2oi-kSVzqBy0nqxuoGPDh5Ixzi8j/edit) (кратко) и [здесь](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0iWGg0969igUrqS98SV_ayly7jhAWHZ/view).